# CSS: Floating IMGs inside floating divs

Tags: css, html, css-float, positioning

I encountered a problem and didn't find a solution for this. I'm pretty confused because I thought this was a very simple requirement.

There are the following elements:

- a surrounding div#wrapper
- div#A, floating left and fixed width
- div#B, floating left (right of #A) and dynamic width
- Inside of div#B there are plenty of images, floating left and fixed width (and height).

Depending on the screen resolution there should be 1, 2, 3, n columns of images on the right part of the screen (next to div#A). Instead of this, container #B is aligned below container #A and uses the full window width.

My alternative attempt was giving #B a float:right and a margin-left (which was greater than the width of #A), but that also didn't work.

I would like to avoid absolute positioning because the height of the surrounding wrapper should increase with its content.

To visualize what I'm talking about, I made the following diagram:
http://abload.de/img/rezeptbilder1k8lsr.png

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you specify the width of div B? Probably you are looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L3kdJ/?

Comment: Thank you, Ilya! This is almost exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way to align #B below #A if theres not enough space to align them side by side?

Comment: You could take Ilya's code and add to B a min-width of an amount that would keep the required number of images in B in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening because..you are having dynamic width for your `div#B`...ans as there are plenty of images and they are aligned next to each other...so eventually div#B grows to 100% width...when it has 100% width then it arrives under the div#A.because 100% + div#A's width cant fit together in a 100% wide screen..you understand???

**1st solution ::**  you may use **`width:calc(100% - div#a's width)`**.it will give div#b a width equals to remaining free space besides div#a

or you may use **`overflow:hidden`** in your div#B...now at first this div will grow eventually to take the width of remaining free space  with a single row of images and once it has 100% width it will create another row of images..but for this your wrapper must have fixed with with `**overflow:auto;**` also..`overflow:auto;` in wrapper will introduce scroll bar when combined with of div A and B is greater than 100%

**EDIT ::**  **[CHECK BROWSER SUPPORTS FOR CALC() HERE](http://caniuse.com/calc)**

note::if you provide us your try our suggestion will be more appropriate

Comment: It should be noted that using calc() comes with certain compatibility issues.  Check caniuse.com for browser support and such.

Comment: overflow: hidden works fine! (as in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3kdJ/)) - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really provide a solution because you haven't provided any code.  (please do so)

That said...  Based on your description and your image, your floats on div#A and div#B are breaking.  The most common reason for this is that your width is adding up to be more than 100% of the width of your div#wrapper (the containing or parent element of the floated elements)

Your floats should always end up equally 100% (less than 100% works but then you have some extra space somewhere etc).

For example...  If you have #wrapper which is 100px wide, then you can have two div's inside which are 50px and 50px wide, or 30px and 70px etc. as adding those values = 100px which is 100%.

So... Why is yours breaking?  I suspect it is because you are trrying to mix a dynamic width element, with a static width element.  Float was never designed do something like this.  There are various ways to achieve it, but which way depends on your code which I don't have.

Other possible reasons why is is breaking is because of too much margin space, too much padding, or even a border on your divs.  The width of an element, by default includes it's padding, margin, and border widths.  If you have a 100px wide div, with 10px of padding on the left and right and a 2 px border the whole way around (2px on each side).  Then you have a div with a total width of 124px.

Comment: I have found a solution through another answer. Thanks anyways for your effort and the additional knowledge you provided!